# Express is not recognized as a internal command

Tags: node.js

I am using npm to install express. I required express on my server.js file, After I used npm install express, I am able to run my file. However, when I tried to run express on the command line, I failed. The same case happened on bower as well. I have configured my environment variable path to APPDATA/Roaming/npm. But the issue persists. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run express in the command-line, you have to install it globally with:

```
npm install -g express
```

Note that omitting the `-g` flag installs express in a directory called `node_modules` inside the current directory. Since this `node_modules` directory is not in the `PATH` that the command line looks for executable files, you cannot run it by just running `express`.

By adding the `-g` flag you are essentially installing express in a directory that is in the system's `PATH`.

Comment: I installed it with the -g flag ,but still didn't work.

Comment: Thx, I made a typo in my environmet config